# Posting form values from phtml to main.php in magento

Tags: magento-1.9

**Update**

Folders are in

**app\design\frontend\base\default\template\recipe_creation\index.php**

**\app\design\frontend\base\default\template\recipe_creation\data.php**

Ie) In my **.phtml** i am posting something like :

```
<div class="main">
        <form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('mymodule_customerpage/recipeCreation/data.php') ?>" method="post" id="form-validate" autocomplete="off">
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                timePicker(10);
            });
        </script>
        <script>
        // timer code starts here --- 
        //var init2 = 50;
            var s;

            function timePicker(vr) {

                if (vr > 0)
                {
                    if (vr > 1) {
                          $('#timer').html('');


                    } else {

                          $('#timer').html('');
                    }
                    vr--;
                    s = setTimeout('timePicker(' + vr + ')', 1000);
                } else {
                    clearInterval(s);

                    //$.post('data.php',{txt_area:$('#rec_name').val(),txt_title:$('#rec_title').val()},function(r){ 
                    $.post('<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB); ?>data.php',{txt_area:$('#rec_name').val(),txt_title:$('#rec_title').val()},function(r){                                                       
                         $('#upd_div').html("Last Updated: "+r);
                    $('#timer').html('Recipe Contents Saved.. ');
                    s = setTimeout('timePicker(' + 10 + ')', 5000);
                    return false;

                    });
                }
            }
        </script>

        <div class="content">
            <div class="heading">
                Recipe Creation Page-- Add Recipe.
            </div>
            <br/><br/>

            <div class="form-group2">  
                 <label>Recipe Name:</label>
                 <input type="text" name="rec_name" id="rec_name" class="form-group2" />
                 <br/><br/>
                 <div class="form-group">  
                    <label>Recipe title:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="rec_title" id="rec_title" class="form-group2" /> 
                </div>  
                 <br/><br/>
                 <br/><br/>
                <div id="timer_upd_dev">
                    <div id="timer">x Secs </div>
                    <div id="upd_div"> </div>
                </div>
            </div>  

        </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script>
```

Is the path given like below correct?

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('mymodule_customerpage/recipeCreation/data.php') ?>" method="post" id="form-validate" autocomplete="off">
```

**app\code\community\Mymodule\Customerpage\controllers\RecipeCreationController.php**

```
class Mymodule_Customerpage_RecipeCreationController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {
public function indexAction()
{
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->renderLayout();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with `Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB);` make sure you place the file with `index.php`

```
<div class="main">
   <form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('mymodule_customerpage/recipeCreation/data.php') ?>" method="post" id="form-validate" autocomplete="off">
    $.post('<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB); ?>myfile.php)
   </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I had tried renaming the index.phtml to index.php file before, but can i place .php files inside the app/design/../templates folder?? or should i move the folder containing index.php and data.php to another location

Comment: put in you main folder where is your `index.php` file

Comment: i have updated the code...path of both the files..can that be given.. in $.post('data.php') how to give the path?

Comment: `\app\design\frontend\base\default\template\recipe_creation\data.php  `put your file   in same folder where your `index.php` `mainfolder\data.php`

Comment: index.php and data.php is in same location folder @Qaisar ie \app\design\frontend\base\default\template\recipe_creation\<index.php, data.php>

Comment: Ok cool, got confused with index.php in my custom  recipeCreation with index.php in magento root folder...@Quisar...Thanks working now!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes that can be Done.

One of the method is to give the link of controller when the from gets submitted.

```
$this->getUrl('YourModule/YourController/YourAction');
```

Comment: Could you please check the updated code, i have tried as above...i get error

Answer (score 0):

First you need to set the block to phtml file like:

```
<block type="module/yourblock" name="anyname"template="foldername/myfile.phtml"/>
```

Then, post your from in phtml like:

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl("module/controller/action"); ?>" method="post">
```

Then, you get your field values in controller like:

```
$postData = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost();
```

then, pass your $postData variable to your block

```
$layout = $this->getLayout();

$block = $layout->getBlock('block_name');
$block->setPostdata($postData);
```

Comment: Hi @Rajan, i dont have any Blocks used in my module...in this case ill create an empty Block?